# Help with a constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, database-design, constraints

I'm creating a table and one of the constraints is that first character must be "G" and then followed by 5 numeric digits:

```
CREATE TABLE PHONE (
  PHONEID CHAR (6) NOT NULL,
  PHONENO NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PHONE_PHONEID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PHONEID),
  CONSTRAINT PHONE_PHONENO_UK UNIQUE (PHONENO)
);
```

How do I do this using sql? I need to do it to phonied

Comment: PLEASE DON'T USE ALL CAPS - IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING!

Comment: sorry, i write my sql in caps, forgot to turn it off, my bad.  i'm using oracle sql developer

Comment: If the first character is always a 'G' there's an argument for it being a separate column (or even not stored in the DB but derived/stripped by the UI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS SQL this would look like this:

```
create table Phone
(
    PhoneId char(6) not null
        constraint Phone_PhoneId_PK primary key
        constraint Phone_PhoneId_CK check (PhoneId like 'G[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    PhoneNumber numeric not null
        constraint Phone_PhoneNumber_UK unique
)

insert Phone
values('G00001', 123) -- pass

insert Phone
values('G0001', 123)  -- fail

insert Phone
values('D0001', 123) -- fail
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, I think it would be:

```
CREATE TABLE PHONE (
  PHONEID CHAR (6) NOT NULL,
  PHONENO NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PHONE_PHONEID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PHONEID),
  CONSTRAINT PHONE_PHONENO_UK UNIQUE (PHONENO),
  CONSTRAINT PHONE_PHONEID_CK CHECK(REGEX_LIKE(PHONEID, '^G\d{5}$'))
);
```

*Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've worked with Oracle, I don't have access now to an Oracle database to validate the above, and this is based on the documentation of [Check Restraints](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2913) and the REGEXP_LIKE function.  Some tweakage might be necessary.

Comment: Oracle  10g+ - prior to that, Oracle doesn't support regex

Comment: Pre 10g you can do it with a RTRIM(PHONEID,'0123456789') = 'G'. May need to check length / space padding. Personally I don't use CHAR ever.